# tf.scan obscures Tensor's shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do some computation within a `tf.scan` loop. My problem is, that it seems that the shape of `tf.slice` seems to either be unknown within the `tf.scan` loop, or unknown compared to to outside of the `tf.scan` loop. The MWE I came up with looks like this:

```
def compute(x, _):
    i = x[0]
    a = x[1]
    print(tf.slice(a, [0], [i]).shape) # First line
    return (i + 1, a)

a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.slice(a, [0], [tf.constant(1)]).shape) # Second line
    x = tf.scan(
        compute,
        tf.zeros(a.shape),
        initializer=(tf.constant(1, tf.int32), a)
    )
```

Which returns the two following lines:

```
(1,)
(?,)
```

Why does `tf.slice` return `(?,)` within the `compute` function? And is there a way to cast the slice into a specific shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `tf.slice` returns a Tensor of shape `(?,)` is simple. This method has the following signature:

```
tf.slice(input_, begin, size, name=None)
```

The pythonic way to rewrite the call `tf.slice(a, [0], [i])` is `a[0:i]`.

At each iteration of `tf.scan`, tensor `i` inside `compute` is derived from the results of the previous iteration, may change and have any arbitrary value. During the compile time, TensorFlow is not able to infer the exact shape of the slice and returns `(?,)`.

In your case, at each iteration `i` is increased and you have slices of various shapes. However, if you do not update `i` and have slices of the same size, the output will still be `(?,)` because the value for `i` comes from outside and previous iterations.

You do not really need to cast the shape of the slice if you are confident in its shape during the runtime. For example, having a varying shape at each iteration as in your case. The main rule with `tf.scan` is to have consistent shapes for the output and initializer tensors, otherwise a `ValueError` is thrown.